# Show custom fields with Search API Database Search + Views

Tags: views, search

I'm indexing the title from one content type using Search API.

When I try to create a Search API Database Search + Views, I can't render the other fields of that content type, I just can render the title. I tried with all custom fields available in the views options, but the view only shows the label for those fields.

Then, I also tried indexing other fields, an image field to be specific. But I got the same results just the labels are showing, something like "The image file. (indexed):" or "Image:".

Is there some way to show in the results of the Search API + Views a custom field like an image field?

Thanks!

Comment: have you add anything in relationships?

Comment: Yes, I added "My Field Image: The image file. (indexed)" and 
"Image: The image file. (indexed)". The other options available in the Relationship section are: "File: Owner", "Indexed Node: Author", "Indexed Node: Comments", "Indexed Node: Tags" and "Indexed Node: Translation source node"